# System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, onesignal

This question probably has been asked multiple times, but none of their [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908301/error-this-operation-cannot-be-performed-after-request-has-been-submitted)  really helped.

I am using OneSignal to send push notifications to all connected clients. I implemented the code in a service and made it a Singleton.

**What I want**
My use case is that I want to send a notification to a user, and immediately send a different notification to another user.

**Problem**
It works only for the first request, after that, I keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.InternalGetRequestStream()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at BingoAPI.Services.NotificationService.SendNotificationAsync(Byte[] buffer) in D:\Bingo\BingoAPI\Services\NotificationService.cs:line 74
```

Here is the implementation:

```
public NotificationService(IOptions<OneSignalNotificationSettigs> oneSignalSettings, IOptions<NotificationTemplates> notificationTemplates)
        {
            this.oneSignalSettings = oneSignalSettings;
            this.notificationTemplates = notificationTemplates;

            // request configuration
            request = WebRequest.Create(oneSignalSettings.Value.EndPoint) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", oneSignalSettings.Value.Authorization);
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        }

        private async Task SendNotificationAsync(byte[] buffer)
        {
            string responseContent = null;
            try
            {
                // here is the error
                var writer = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                await writer.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                writer.Close();

                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                responseContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
               // LOGGING
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have to mention, I tried to add this service as Transient, and it worked. But, I don't think it is a long term solution because this has to be reinitialized for every request

Comment: I know it is not a direct answer, but as you use asp net core I would suggest using a HttpClient through the IHttpClientFactory and use dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using HttpClientFactory instead of HttpWebRequest although I could make it transient. But that does not look like a solution for me in the long term run because a lot of extra stuff has to be reinitialized with every request. And it's even less code.

```
public NotificationService(IOptions<OneSignalNotificationSettigs> oneSignalSettings, IOptions<NotificationTemplates> notificationTemplates,
                                   IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            this.oneSignalSettings = oneSignalSettings;
            this.notificationTemplates = notificationTemplates;

            // request configuration
            httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", oneSignalSettings.Value.Authorization);
            request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oneSignalSettings.Value.EndPoint);           
        }

        private async Task SerializeNotificationAsync(Object obj)
        {            
            var param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            var data = new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await SendNotificationAsync(data);                                                
        }


        private async Task SendNotificationAsync(StringContent buffer)
        {            
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(request.RequestUri, buffer);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // logg error

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Singleton means the application every subsequent request uses the same instance.

This means all the two request use the same `HttpWebRequest`.

Since your SendNotificationAsync is async method. If you call this method twice at same time. It will use the same `HttpWebRequest(request)` to send the request.

The error tells you that the first `HttpWebRequest(request)` is submitted and not executed complete, we couldn't submit `HttpWebRequest(request)` again.

In my opinion, you should register the service as `Transient`, since each we couldn't re-use the `HttpWebRequest(request)` .